# Finding the position of an element in a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code: `array_search($key, $array)`. $key is any number from 1 to 10. $array looks like this:

```
id    name
 1    foo
 2    bar 
 3    lol 
 4    asdf
```

I just want to find the name's position in the array. So if I had "foo", i'd get 0, if I had "lol", I'd have 2. Any help?

Comment: You want to search by key and return the key?

Comment: Could you reword the question? I do not understand it.

Comment: So what is wrong with your code? array_search($key, $array) should be fine.

Comment: Also, could you provide a print_r of your array?

Comment: i have updated tested code below, check "japanPro"

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = 2
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($value['id'] == $id) {
        echo $value['name'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = array_search($foo, array_values($array));
```

Err, I think I mistook what you meant by your input array.

This is probably what you want:

```
function find_position($key, array $array, $col)
{
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($array as $item) /* or as $i => $item, not sure what you want */
  {
    if ($item[$col] == $key) return $i;
    ++$i;
  }
  return NULL;
}

$i = find_position('foo', $array, 'name');
```

Regarding the comment in the above code... obviously if you use it, then you don't need the `$i = 0` or `$++i`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [array_values](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to re-index your array to a zero index.

```
$index = array_search($foo, array_values($array));
```

This would return:

```
echo array_search('foo', array_values($array)); // 0
echo array_search('bar', array_values($array)); // 1
echo array_search('lol', array_values($array)); // 2
echo array_search('asdf', array_values($array)); // 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $array = array("1"=>"foo","2"=>"bar","3"=>"lol","4"=>"asdf");

    $value="foo";

    $key = array_search($value, $array);

    $pos =array_search($key, array_keys($array));

    echo "element pos is: ". ($pos);

?>
```

Comment: The first `array_search` wouldn't return a correct value because it would be looking for the value of the key in the array, which would not exist as a value.

Comment: if element dont exits , it will return 0. can you put some more example.

Comment: The question asks to find the position of the key, not the position of the value. ie. `$key = 2`

Comment: Can u read this => "I just want to find the name's position in the array. So if I had "foo", i'd get 0, if I had "lol", I'd have 2. Any help?" its exactly what he is looking for..